# Install Windows 7 without DVD drive

Tags: windows, boot, usb, drivers

I am trying to install Windows 7 on my laptop from a USB drive. I used the Microsoft tool to make a bootable Windows 7 USB drive and it boots, but when I try to install it says:

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Might I inquire as to why someone with the name of 'linuxer' is installing Windows?

Comment: It's for work. Otherwise I'd be on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You properly plugged the USB thumb drive into an USB 3.0 port (blue). Windows 7 doesn't have an USB 3.0 driver build in.

So you must add the USB 3.0 driver first to your boot.wim (mount the WIM, use DISM /Add-Driver to add the driver, commit and unmount the WIM) or connect the USB drive to an USB 2.0 port.

Comment: I have successfully added USB 3.0 driver and able to use mouse and keyboard but after click on Install button it's shows the same message

Comment: @maruf if you use a M2 MVMe SSD, also add the MVMe drivers to the boot.wim

Comment: It is a USB 3.0 Pendrive and the computer I've used is HP ProDesk 400 G4, the USB 2.0 on rear side its working but I'm curious about font USB 3.0 port, is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: @maruf maybe you [added it to the wrong index](https://superuser.com/a/863555/174557)

Comment: I've followed the instruction from this guide:https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/mini-pcs/nuc-kits/Install-Win7-to-USB3_0-Computers.pdf and have been used DISM GUI Tool and there is a way to see the index and description for boot.wim and install.wim

Comment: @maticandre1981 I have copied drivers from Win7 folder only and don't added the drivers inside HCSwitch folder. Is this the reason for this problem?

Comment: @maruf add both drivers

Answer (score 3):

Switch from *SATA* to *AHCI*.

Follow the aforementioned instructions for booting into your computer’s BIOS, then check your HDD or storage settings. Turn off SATA, switching to AHCI, and reboot normally, then re-attempt installation of Windows 7.

Comment: My BIOS only allows AHCI.

Comment: And just to be clear. I DO NOT have a DVD drive on the laptop, nor do I have an external one.

Answer (score 0):

More suggestions:

1. Change boot order so that your USB thumb drive is first
2. Does this laptop have some sort of RAID set up?  If so, that same error message will show up.
3. Re-create the flash drive (or use a different one) to verify that it's not an issue with your installation media.
4. Use gparted (I believe you can run it from the Ubuntu Live USB image) to format the drive as NTFS (or just completely remove all formatting from the drive).

Answer (score 0):

A popular cause for this error is Windows Setup losing its connection to the USB disk after getting to the welcome screen. The solution [from answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/a-required-cddvd-device-driver-is-missing-usb/61eda679-66cc-4512-b175-d02871394461):

> When Windows is asking for driver, just click Cancel. You will be
>   brought back to the welcome screen. At the welcome screen, remove your
>   USB drive, insert it back to DIFFERENT USB PORT. Click Install Now
>   again.

Answer (score 0):

may I ask what "microsoft tool" are you using?
Because its all the problem caused due to incorrect tool/method used to make a bootable drive.

You may use [ISO to USB](http://www.isotousb.com/) for your quick and easy bootable usb drive.