# Win8 downgrade - Windows 7 installation "Driver not found"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-installation, windows-installer

I have an **Asus R500VD** laptop which came with the preinstalled Windows 8. As actually this computer will be used by my grandmother (and she's only using win 7) I'd like to downgrade it.

Thanks to other thread here, I was able to successfully boot computer from Windows 7 USB stick, but unfortunately during install I got a message:

```
A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. (...)
```

and I can't get pass it... This is what I've done:

- I've downloaded all drivers from Asus Website (http://www.asus.com/pl/supportonly/R500VD/HelpDesk_Download/), unzip and copied to visible location for windows 7 installation - I've picked each one of them, none has helped.
- As I belive it's some kind of problem with SATA/RAID/AHCI drivers I went to Intel site and downloaded various "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" drivers - a lot of them were recognized by win7, but none of them helped.

Does anyone have an idea what can I do next?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you disabled the CD/DVD drive in the bios and tried the installation without it being visible?

Comment: is that you have connected any external CD/DVD drive through USB in your laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message happens when you try to install Windows 7 via USB flash drive and use the USB device on a USb 3.0 port. Windows 7 doesn't support USb 3.0 out of the box, so you must [inject the USB 3.0 drivers into the Boot.wim with DISM first](http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-windows-7-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/).

```
dism /mount-wim /wimfile:boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:mount

dism /image:mount /add-driver:"usb3" /recurse

dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:mount /commit
```

[image]

Now copy the modified `boot.wim` to the flash drive.