# Stupid CD/DVD driver error trying to install windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 Ultimate Edition (Win7_Ult_SP1_English_x32.iso) on a newly wiped laptop using a bootable USB key I made with Rufus. However it's going straight from "Setup is starting..." to

**"Load Driver**

A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD or USB flash drive, please insert it now.

Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step."

This laptop doesn't even physically have a CD/DVD drive; there is no disk tray! This is ridiculous! Help!

Comment: if you use the flash drive on an USB 3.0 port inject the USB 3.0 driver first into the Boot.wim: http://superuser.com/a/863555/174557

Comment: I got as far as the second step. This is what I'm putting into command prompt:

Comment: additionally not specifying the driver .exe and leaving it at '\USB3' yields error 0x80010105 DISM failed. No operation performed. For more innformation, review the log file.

Comment: you have to extract the Exe. DISM only accepts extracted driver with INF + dll + sys files in a folder