# Can't install Windows 7 using bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, bios, windows-installation, asus-laptop

I have a laptop Asus X453S. And it has a Windows 10. I tried to downgrade it to Windows 7 and I was able to clean the partition. I already set up the BIOS. And when I tried to boot the USB there is a message “Reboot And Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device”.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to make your USB bootable, which you can do by following the steps in this webpage: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200124(v=ws.11).aspx

Assuming you have a .iso file of Windows 7, simply copying it onto the USB won't work. You have to image/burn it onto the USB.

There are 3rd party tools such as ImgBurn (http://www.imgburn.com/)

But I prefer using CommandLineDiskImager (https://github.com/davidferguson/CommandLineDiskImager/releases/tag/0.0.0.3).

Although you'll have to use command prompt to burn the .iso (instructions can be found at https://github.com/davidferguson/CommandLineDiskImager), you don't have to install applications, and potential bloatware/viruses.

Comment: I just copied it and paste it to USB and changed the setting to Better Performance and NTFS. It works in my other laptop.. like Lenovo Win8 to Win7 and Acer Win7 to Win7..

Comment: I tried PowerISO and it works now but the problem is I have this message after "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click ok"

Comment: @Vena [see my answer](https://superuser.com/a/863555/174557) on how to add USB3 drivers to Windows 7 to be able to boot from USB

Comment: @Ramhound I include that phrase exactly for that purpose - so that its taken as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: You could just submit an answer.  Saying something isn't a comment makes that the statement a comment.  Removed the comment from your answer.